# How come only Yaakov is Bikesh Shalva?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-vayeishev

Rashi comments at the beginning of this week's *parsha*, that Yaakov requested to sit in tranquility:

> וישב, בִּקֵּשׁ יַעֲקֹב לֵישֵׁב בְּשַׁלְוָה, קָפַץ עָלָיו רָגְזוֹ שֶׁל יוֹסֵף – צַדִּיקִים מְבַקְּשִׁים לֵישֵׁב בְּשַׁלְוָה, אָמַר הַקָּבָּ"ה לֹא דַיָּן לַצַּדִּיקִים מַה שֶּׁמְּתֻקָּן לָהֶם לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, אֶלָּא שֶׁמְּבַקְּשִׁים לֵישֵׁב בְּשַׁלְוָה בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה:

Why is it only Yaakov who makes this request? All the *avos* underwent traumatic experiences. Avraham with *kivshan ha'eish*, Yitzchak with the *akeida*, Yosef with the hatred from his brothers and the *nisyonos* of Egypt etc etc. But they seemingly don't make this request. Why is it only Yaakov?

Comment: Maybe they all did but Rashi didn't mention it there?

Comment: וישב אברהם בבאר שבע and Sarah died. וישב יצחק בגרר and Avimelech messed with Rivkah.

Answer (score 1):

" בִּקֵּשׁ " in this context doesn't mean asked. It means was looking for.And the Medrash that Rashi brings goes on to include all Tzadikim. Not just Yaakov.

Yaakov seems to have been singled out because he seems to have had the most difficult life of all of the Avos.

The Meforshim who ask how do you see in the words וישב יַעֲקֹב anything about wanting to live בְּשַׁלְוָה (inter alia) explain that the next Posuk starts אֵ֣לֶּה  תֹּֽלְד֣וֹת  יַֽעֲקֹ֗ב יוֹסֵ֞ף. What is the connection and what about Reuven?  The answer is that problems like the story of Yosef *typify* the life of Yaakov. He wants to sit בְּשַׁלְוָה and instead of that happening the next thing that happens and is mentioned in the story of Yosef. This is the way his life went. Mention him wanting to לֵישֵׁב בְּשַׁלְוָה and then a new problem will be mentioned.

I  don't know if that would be true about the other Avos.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you add a link to the medrash? That would make it even better.

Comment: See a Mekroes Gedolas Chumash. Rashi brings down when the Medrash and the Sifsei Chachomim  on Rashi says this pshat